# Open a modal from another component in React bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to open a modal from another component. this is in my parent component:

```
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ModalB from './ModalB';

function App() {
  const [showA, setShowA] = useState(false);
  const [showB, setShowB] = useState(false);

  const handleCloseA = () => setShowA(false);
  const handleShowA = () => setShowA(true);

  const handleShowB = ({ handleShow }) => {
    setShowB(handleShow);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShowA}>Open A</Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShowB}>Open B</Button>

        <Modal show={showA} onHide={handleCloseA}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>In Modal A</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
        </Modal>

        <ModalB isModalVisible={showB}></ModalB>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And Modal B component:

```
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { propTypes } from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Image';

const ModalB = (props) => {
    const [showB, setShowB] = useState(false);
    const handleCloseB = () => setShowB(false);
    const handleShowB = () => setShowB(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={props.isModalVisible} onHide={handleCloseB}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>In Modal B</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );

}

export default ModalB;
```

The problem is to display B from the main component. While displaying modalA is simple, I don't understand how to tell B to display from the main component.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "show" state from `ModalB` and pass in the `handleShowB` handler from the parent.

```
const ModalB = ({ isModalVisible, handleShowB }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={props.isModalVisible} onHide={handleShowB}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>In Modal B</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In parent pass `handleShowB` handler. Here we just pass an anonymous callback to call the `setShowB` state updater and update the `showB` state to be false.

```
<ModalB
  isModalVisible={showB}
  handleShowB={() => setShowB(false)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> const handleShowB = ({ handleShow }) => {
> setShowB(handleShow);   };

Why do you need `handleShow` if this is undefined?

Just update your state based on current state and the rest of your code would work fine.

```
const handleShowB = () => setShowB(!showB);
```

This will trigger the current modal state (weather hide/show) for `ModalB` component and it will render accordingly.

Here's working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/show-multiple-modals-edv6y